# Why negative end index doesn't work with array slice in js

Tags: javascript

When I use this

```
let arr=[1,2,3,4];
console.log(arr.slice(-1)) // it gives 4
```

But while using

```
console.log(arr.slice(-1,-1)) // it gives []
```

for any value of end index if the start index is negative ,it doesn't gives output ,I am not able to understand this can anyone pls explain ,thanks

Comment: You start at 1 before the end, and stop 1 before the end, so there is no range to slice

Comment: No matter what value I am passing in the second argument ,positive or negative it always returns empty array

Comment: Referencing [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice), can you indicate what result you were *expecting* and *why*?

Answer (score 1):

From the [`Array.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) docs:

> `start`
>
> Negative index counts back from the end of the array — `if start < 0`, `start + array.length` is used.
>
> ---
>
> `end`
>
> Negative index counts back from the end of the array — `if end < 0`, `end + array.length` is used.

---

So you start at `1 from the end`, and end `1 from the end`.

This is a 'empty' selection, and therefore the return value will be `[]`

---

If you eg do `(-2, -1)` you'll get from `2 before the end`, to `1 before the end`

```js
const arr = [1,2,3,4];
console.log(arr.slice(-2, -1)) // [ 3 ]
```

Comment: so  console.log(arr.slice(-2, -1)) == console.log(arr.slice(2, 3)) // [ 3 ] ?